# Printed PDF says "invalidfont" and "OFFENDING COMMAND" when printing from Chrome

Tags: chrome, printing, postscript

I have a OKI MC562dnw hooked up to my network and CUPS (*2.1.3*) installed on my laptop (*Ubuntu 16.04.3*) containing PostScript-drivers from OKI's site.

Whenever I print a PDF-file from a website in Google Chrome (*Version 63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)*) then the printer prints an error instead of the PDF. The error says:

```
ERROR:
invalidfont
OFFENDING COMMAND;
awidthshow
STACK:
-mark-
-mark-
-mark-
```

Previously I had the same issue printing from file as well, but then I installed *xpdf:i386* as a solution posted on another forum, which made printing from file working but not Google Chrome. I have tried rebooting and updating since, but to no avail.

This issue is not present in Firefox.

All help is appreciated, getting tired of wasting paper.

EDIT: Printing from Chrome has worked previously and suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Same for me with oki mc362dn under ubuntu 18.04
It could be a postscript incompatibility.
I'm now looking for a way to use PCL driver